# When I deploy to Azure, It just get internal server error (500), no more

Tags: angular, azure, .net-core, publish, http-status-code-500

Hellow EveryBody, I am a Azure junior.

**What I have**

- VS 2019
- .NET Core 3.1 with Angular 9+
- Deployed to Azure Web App
- The site works locally
- When I deploy to Azure, It just get internal server error (500), no more ...
- I can't see UseDeveloperExceptionPage
- Used EFCore / Dapper ORM to .mdf, I guess is this problem

Below Image is

VS Template Publish success and my app publish error Compared

https://github.com/johch3n611u/Side-Project-Personal-Branding-Image-Web/blob/master/Personal-Branding-Image/Website_Background/prod_different_part.png?raw=true

**What I can try ?**

If you need more information this github code .

https://github.com/johch3n611u/Side-Project-Personal-Branding-Image-Web/tree/master/Personal-Branding-Image/Website_Background

Answer (score 0):

500 internal error is generic issue. You may need to check full error message that you see on the server.

Comment: THX u very much, My project used VS .NET Core - Angular Template , I try to customized change some kit versions, So some CLI set seem run away, I try to used ftp to check file and code, Than i don't notice angular build file path error. I change path and then it is working ... But i still not know how to check error status code back ☹ ...